# Replace a string value with a wildcard in array key (like: width=* => width=100)

Tags: php, arrays

We retrieve a lot of images from a server and all those sizes are random. We need to make them all the same.

The code posted works great if I know the fixed size, but I'd like it to work long term so even when the source changes the string file width.

I searched for a while and found some code with complete functions that might make this possible, but nothing with a single wildcard in the array key.

Is this not an option?

I tried with *, \d+ and some other regex variables but failed.

```
function resize ($width = '150'){
$raw_img_src = http://longurl/img.file?width=[random];
$replace_sizes = array("width=[random]" => "width=$width");
$img_src = strtr($raw_img_src, $replace_sizes);
}
```

The end result should be where this
http://longurl/img.file?width=123;
Should be changed into
http://longurl/img.file?width=150;

Thanks.

Update: these are both great answers, thanks. We took the shortest one.

```
// OR
$img_src = preg_replace('#\bwidth=\d+#', "width=$width", $raw_img_src);
$img_src = preg_replace('#\bheight=\d+#', "height=$height", $img_src);
$img_src = rawurlencode($img_src);

// OR
$parts = parse_url($raw_img_src);
$uri_parts = explode('?', $raw_img_src)[0];
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$query['width'] = $width;
$query['height'] = $height;
$img_src = $uri_parts.'?'.http_build_query($query);
$img_src = rawurlencode($img_src);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your needs:

```
function resize ($width = '150'){
    $raw_img_src = 'http://longurl/img.file?width=[random]';
    $img_src = preg_replace('#width=\[random\]#', "width=$width", $raw_img_src);
}
```

but it could be if `[random]` is a real width:

```
function resize ($width = '150'){
    // by example http://longurl/img.file?width=512
    $raw_img_src = 'http://longurl/img.file?width=[random]';
    $img_src = preg_replace('#width=\d+#', "width=$width", $raw_img_src);
}
```

If you wanna use `[]` think about quoting, all special chars need to be quoted:
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: It does actually just contain a number, like this ?height=681&ch=sha2995a9ac01&width=920&resize=5. I like it is short as well, will try and get back.

Comment: @KimK Ok so my 2nd code should do the trick. The given regex is the simplest you can use but you can add controls by example `#\bwidth=\d+#` in order to be sure of replacing the good part (avoiding to replace a minwidth=xxx ou maxwidth=xxx). Tell me if you have any trouble

Comment: Thanks @Unkle. I'll use your answer because it works in 3 lines and not 7. Both solutions are great though. BTW, Adding \b did add 20ms to the result.

Comment: Thank you @KimK. you're right other answers are technically right too and it's important to specify that some "selectors" may have significant impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex but how about this way without using any **regex**. It doesn't require any specific **order** of your `width` parameter in the url. Also you've more control over on your parameters to do modifications.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://longurl/img.file?width=123&name=kim';
$parts = parse_url($url);
$uri_parts = explode('?', $url)[0];
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$query['width'] = 150;
echo $uri_parts.'?'.http_build_query($query);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
http://longurl/img.file?width=150&name=kim
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/rImeg

Comment: Since our string looks like this: ?height=681&ch=sha2995a9ac01&width=920&resize=5 this might actually work. Will look inot it and report back.

Comment: @KimK. I am very eager to know that mate :), Let me know. Best of luck

Comment: @KimK. If you want to update the width and the height regardless of the order in which they can occur in the string, I am voting +1 for this answer and will delete mine.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes it is not in any particular order. Your answer took longest with 141ms to replace the one value. This comes in second with 70ms and the other one with preg_replace is fastest with 54ms. Any pros / cons for selecting one of these answers? If not I'll take the fastest one.

Comment: This answer uses parse_url and takes the structure of the url into account. The other answer might be faster, but will also replace `dontchangethiswidth=999`

Comment: Ok, that was covered by adding \b though. However, when adding that is also adds 20ms to the result making it a tie in terms of speed ;-). I'll keep them both but accept the shorter answer, 3 lines instead of 7.